# How to get variable from 1 class to another class in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am writing application to record call and upload all file was record.

I have problem when get path file name and upload it into my server.

I want to when 1 file was record success then it will upload.

I have 2 class: 
Class `AudioRecorder` to record call.

```
public class AudioRecorder {

    static String fileName;

    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    public void start() {
        File directory = new File(fileName).getParentFile();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();
                }

    public String courseGet(String startDate) {
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/GhiAmCuocGoi/"
                + startDate + configPreferenceManager.getPathFormat();
    }
}
```

In this class `fileName` variable is contain PATH to file record.

And this class to get `Event` when `incoming and outcoming call`.
When call state is end, it will `UploadFile`.

How to get values of variable `fileName` of class `Audiorecorder` to `fileToUploadPath` variable of class bellow.

In this class is:

```
TelephonyManager telManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

telManager.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

     if (state != pState) {
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK && callInfoPreferenceManager.getCallState()) { 
            Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    callInfoPreferenceManager.getName() + " "
                            + callInfoPreferenceManager.getPhoneNumber()
                            + "\n" + "Start recording!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE && callInfoPreferenceManager.getCallState() == CALLING) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Record success.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // I WILL UPLOAD AT HERE. AFTER RECORD SUCCESS
            MultipartUploadRequest req = new MultipartUploadRequest(this, serverUrlString)
                .addFileToUpload(fileToUploadPath, paramNameString);
        }
    }
}, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways we can access variable on one object from other . These are main two ways

1) Create getter method for the variables  getFileName() and access through the created object.

2) If the variable is static then you can write static getter function. 
for example : public static String getVal();

There are other ways like accessing the method directly by defining the variable as public , protected or default but not recommeded as it violates OOP principles.

More advanced ways are through Refection.

Answer (score 0):

`AudioRecorder.fileName` is the best way to access file name because `fileName` is a `static` member of the class. and will be loaded when `class` is getting loaded into the memory.

Here, AudioRecorder is a public class, So this variable named `fileName` will be access anywhere in the project Scope.

So, `AudioRecorder.fileName` is a better way to access.

```
 MultipartUploadRequest req = new MultipartUploadRequest(this, serverUrlString)
                .addFileToUpload(AudioRecorder.fileName, paramNameString);
    // File Name passed as a parameter. 

    /*You should also put a check wheather this variable contains any actual 
    FileName that exists in Phone Memory(Either Internal/External) or Not  ?? */
```

Comment: I'm using `AudioRecorder audioRecorder = new AudioRecorder();` but
`audioRecorder.fileName` not found in this class.

Comment: its a `static` member so no need of any `Object` to access that perticular Variable `fileName`. so just try Once what I have Recommended to you. 
`static` member variables are shared among all the object as a Single Entity. So, @Luna either you use `audioRecorder.fileName` or `AudioRecorder.fileName` all will be gives you the same. Thanks